# Connection refused when making curl request inside docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a nginx webserver with docker compose with the following web apps:

```
example.com
api.example.com
```

I can curl both sides from outside, but I need to curl from one web page to the other one.

```
curl example.com -> host not found
curl nginx -> returns exmaple.com app
```

I tried to set the servername to api.nginx and curling this, but then it says `host not found`

So how do I have to set the configuration so both apps can communicate?

docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:

### Applications Code Container #############################

    applications:
      image: tianon/true
      volumes:
        - ${APPLICATION}:/var/www

### Workspace Utilities Container ###########################

    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
        dockerfile: "Dockerfile-${PHP_VERSION}"
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
      tty: true
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### PHP-FPM Container #######################################

    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
          - INSTALL_TOKENIZER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TOKENIZER}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
        dockerfile: "Dockerfile-${PHP_VERSION}"
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      expose:
        - "9000"
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
      networks:
        - backend

### PHP Worker Container #####################################

    php-worker:
      build:
        context: ./php-worker
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      networks:
        - backend

### MySQL Container #########################################

    mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend
        - frontend

### Redis Container #########################################

    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/redis:/data
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      networks:
        - backend

### Caddy Server Container ##################################

    caddy:
      build: ./caddy
      volumes_from:
        - applications
      volumes:
        - ${CADDY_CUSTOM_CADDYFILE}:/etc/Caddyfile
        - ${CADDY_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/caddy
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}:/root/.caddy
      ports:
        - "${CADDY_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${CADDY_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Adminer Container ####################################

    adminer:
      build:
        context: ./adminer
        args:
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${ADM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
      ports:
        - "${ADM_PORT}:8080"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Laravel Echo Server #######################################
    laravel-echo-server:
      build:
        context: ./laravel-echo-server
      volumes:
        - ./laravel-echo-server/laravel-echo-server.json:/app/laravel-echo-server.json:ro
      ports:
        - "${LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_PORT}:6001"
      links:
        - redis
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Networks Setup ############################################

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: "bridge"
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"

### Volumes Setup #############################################

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: "local"
  percona:
    driver: "local"
  mssql:
    driver: "local"
  postgres:
    driver: "local"
  memcached:
    driver: "local"
  redis:
    driver: "local"
  neo4j:
    driver: "local"
  mariadb:
    driver: "local"
  mongo:
    driver: "local"
  minio:
    driver: "local"
  rethinkdb:
    driver: "local"
  phpmyadmin:
    driver: "local"
  adminer:
    driver: "local"
  aerospike:
    driver: "local"
  caddy:
    driver: "local"
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: "local"
  elasticsearch-plugins:
    driver: "local"
```

Comment: can you post your `docker-compose`?

Comment: added the relevant part

Comment: the relevant part is as well the configuration of your web apps since that will define how you can access them

Comment: I just mount in the php files so I have a clear separation

Comment: ah ok sorry, I thought you have seperate containers for each web app

Comment: What does it mean "but I need to curl from one web page to the other one"?  Do you need to `curl example.com` from `api.example.com` php code?

Comment: @lifeisfoo exactly. When I run the code on a normal webserver on windows it works fine, but in combination with docker compose it does not resolve the names if you make a request from the inside

Comment: What is the `php-fpm` service referenced in the `depends_on` tag? Is it the service that runs the php code?

Comment: I added the whole compose file, think this will be easier to understand then. The code container will be mounted inside the nginx container that will load the php container.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the extra hosts to the extra_hosts in my `php-fpm` service:

https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/435

```
php-fpm:
  build:
    context: ./php-fpm
    args:
      - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
      - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
      - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
      - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
      - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
      - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
      - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
      - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
      - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
      - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
      - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
      - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
      - INSTALL_TOKENIZER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TOKENIZER}
      - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
      - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
      - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
      - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile-${PHP_VERSION}"
  volumes_from:
    - applications
  volumes:
    - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
  expose:
    - "9000"
  depends_on:
    - workspace
  extra_hosts:
    - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
    - "example.com:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
    - "api.example.com:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
```